# Output returns 2 instead of 1 for Codeforces

Tags: python

[image: Problem]

In my program, everything works fine for the problem, except one test, where the input is shown here: [image]

This is my code:

```
while True:
    n = int(input())
    if n in range(1, 1001):
        break


total_solutions = 0
mini_solutions = 0
for i in range(n):
    solutions = input()
    for num in solutions:
        if num == "1":
            mini_solutions += 1
    if mini_solutions >=2:
        total_solutions += 1
        mini_solutions = 0

print(total_solutions)
```

I can't find out why it returns 2 instead of 1. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mini_solutions should be reset to 0 regardless of whether more than 2 of them know the answer or not. If you take it out of the if-statement then the solution will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
n = int(input())
if n in range(1, 1001):
    break

total_solutions = 0
for i in range(n):
solutions = input().split(" ")
mini_solutions = 0
for num in solutions:
    if num == "1":
        mini_solutions += 1
if mini_solutions >=2:
    total_solutions += 1
    mini_solutions = 0

print(total_solutions)
```

This works fine, check it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it is much shorter and more readable, so you can catch bugs faster

```
n = int(input())
solvable_problems = 0
for _ in range(n):
    problem = [int (i) for i in input().split()]
    if sum(problem) >= 2:
        solvable_problems += 1

print(solvable_problems)
```